# Insert Statement in Stored Procedure trying to Update the Pre-Shared Key/ID column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert query that looks like its trying to override the `ID` column when its executed, but I have not told it to do this and I have no idea why its behaving this way.

The error I am getting is:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table  can
>   only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   ON.

The thing I do not understand is why its trying to explicitly insert some value into the ID field!!??

Initially the query was like this

```
Insert MyTable Values(<total of 55 values>)
```

then I read somewhere to try specifying the columns so I did and the error changed to:

> Cannot convert 'NULL' to datatype int.

and it pointed to the insert line....

the query itself it being built within the `SP` and executed, a bunch of `VarChar` parameters are used to build the query

any ideas whats happening here?

**UPDATE**

OK ill post one of the variations im trying to get working right now.....I added a column on this table I am inserting to earlier today.... not sure if that would cause a problem somewhere? it is included in the insert so it shouldnt be a problem

```
declare @ContainerPKID varchar(10),@BuyerID varchar(10),@FeedlotID varchar(10),@Date_Purchase varchar(20),@Sex varchar(10),@Origin_Country varchar(10),@Origin_State varchar(5)
declare @Origin_City varchar(25),@Purchase_Name varchar(40),@HDCT_In varchar(10),@Cattle_Cost_Cwt varchar(10),@Weight_Pay_Hd varchar(10)
declare @Equity varchar(10),@Interest_Rate varchar(10),@Proj_Date_In varchar(20),@Proj_Weight_Out_Avg varchar(10),@Proj_Ship_Date varchar(20),@Proj_CONV varchar(10),@Proj_Ration_Cost varchar(10)
declare @Proj_Yardage varchar(10),@Proj_DL varchar(10),@Proj_ADG varchar(10),@Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd varchar(10),@Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd varchar(10),@Proj_MED varchar(10),@Proj_Yardage_Hd varchar(10)
declare @Proj_DL_Cost_Hd varchar(10),@Proj_Freight_Hd varchar(10),@Proj_Interest_Hd varchar(10),@Proj_Realizers varchar(10),@Proj_TotalCost_Hd varchar(10),@Proj_Gain varchar(10),@Proj_DOF varchar(10)
declare @Proj_Breakeven varchar(10),@Proj_COG varchar(10),@Proj_Futures varchar(10),@Proj_Basis varchar(10),@Diff_On_Formula varchar(10),@Hdg_Live_Cost varchar(10),@Proj_PL_HD varchar(10)
declare @Proj_PL_HD_Hdg varchar(10),@Proj_PL_HD_Net varchar(10),@Proj_ROI varchar(10),@Purchase_Contract_No varchar(20),@Age varchar(10),@Condtion varchar(10),@Quality varchar(16)
declare @Breed varchar(10),@Source_Loc varchar(16),@Date_In varchar(20),@Weight_Offtruck_Tot varchar(10),@Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot varchar(10),@Act_Pay_Weight_Tot varchar(10),@Purchase_Type varchar(10),@Notes varchar(256)
declare @Comma varchar(3), @SA varchar(10), @SQL varchar(MAX), @PurchaseValues varchar(max)

    set @PurchaseValues = 'NULL|1|NULL|6/21/2016|S|USA|NULL|NULL|aaaa|0|5|55|0|0.0500|6/21/2016|444|2016-07-23 10:00|1|23|0|0.0300|12|2.75|4.47|0|0.00|0.22|0|0.02|0|7.46|389|32.42|1.68|0.01|44|0|0|44.000|187.90|0|187.90|15,174.47|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL'

  set @SA = ''''
  set @Comma = ', '

  set @ContainerPKID = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 1)
  set @BuyerID = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 2)
  set @FeedlotID = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 3)
  set @Date_Purchase = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 4)
  set @Sex = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 5)
  set @Origin_Country = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 6)
  set @Origin_State = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 7)
  set @Origin_City = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 8)
  set @Purchase_Name = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 9)
  set @HDCT_In = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 10)
  set @Cattle_Cost_Cwt = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 11)
  set @Weight_Pay_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 12)
  set @Equity = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 13)
  set @Interest_Rate = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 14)
  set @Proj_Date_In = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 15)
  set @Proj_Weight_Out_Avg = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 16)
  set @Proj_Ship_Date = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 17)
  set @Proj_CONV = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 18)
  set @Proj_Ration_Cost = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 19)
  set @Proj_Yardage = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 20)
  set @Proj_DL = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 21)
  set @Proj_ADG = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 22)
  set @Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 23)
  set @Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 24)
  set @Proj_MED = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 25)
  set @Proj_Yardage_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 26)
  set @Proj_DL_Cost_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 27)
  set @Proj_Freight_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 28)
  set @Proj_Interest_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 29)
  set @Proj_Realizers = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 30)
  set @Proj_TotalCost_Hd = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 31)
  set @Proj_Gain = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 32)
  set @Proj_DOF = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 33)
  set @Proj_Breakeven = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 34)
  set @Proj_COG = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 35)
  set @Proj_Futures = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 36)
  set @Proj_Basis = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 37)
  set @Diff_On_Formula = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 38)
  set @Hdg_Live_Cost = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 39)
  set @Proj_PL_HD = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 40)
  set @Proj_PL_HD_Hdg = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 41)
  set @Proj_PL_HD_Net = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 42)
  set @Proj_ROI = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 43)
  set @Purchase_Contract_No = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 44)
  set @Age = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 45)
  set @Condtion = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 46)
  set @Quality = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 47)
  set @Breed = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 48)
  set @Source_Loc = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 49)
  set @Date_In = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 50)
  set @Weight_Offtruck_Tot = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 51)
  set @Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 52)
  set @Act_Pay_Weight_Tot = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 53)
  set @Purchase_Type = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 54)
  set @Notes = (select Data from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 55)

  if @Date_Purchase <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Date_Purchase = @SA + @Date_Purchase + @SA
    end

  if @Sex <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Sex = @SA + @Sex + @SA
    end

  if @Origin_Country <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Origin_Country = @SA + @Origin_Country + @SA
    end

  if @Origin_State <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Origin_State = @SA + @Origin_State + @SA
    end

  if @Origin_City <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Origin_City = @SA + @Origin_City + @SA
    end

  if @Purchase_Name <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Purchase_Name = @SA + @Purchase_Name + @SA
    end

  if @Proj_Date_In <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Proj_Date_In = @SA + @Proj_Date_In + @SA
    end

  if @Proj_Ship_Date <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Proj_Ship_Date = @SA + @Proj_Ship_Date + @SA
    end

  if @Purchase_Contract_No <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Purchase_Contract_No = @SA + @Purchase_Contract_No + @SA
    end

  if @Purchase_Contract_No <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Purchase_Contract_No = @SA + @Purchase_Contract_No + @SA
    end

  if @Age <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Age = @SA + @Age + @SA
    end

  if @Condtion <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Condtion = @SA + @Condtion + @SA
    end

  if @Quality <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Quality = @SA + @Quality + @SA
    end

  if @Breed <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Breed = @SA + @Breed + @SA
    end

  if @Source_Loc <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Source_Loc = @SA + @Source_Loc + @SA
    end

  if @Date_In <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Date_In = @SA + @Date_In + @SA
    end

  if @Purchase_Type <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Purchase_Type = @SA + @Purchase_Type + @SA
    end

  if @Notes <> 'NULL'
    begin
      set @Notes = @SA + @Notes + @SA
    end

    --UPDATED TO ACCOUNT FOR A NEW COLUMN 'CustomerID'    NOTE: Ty took out the single quotations around NULL.  That didnt work so changed to a 1
    --INSERT INTO tblPurchases 
    --VALUES (
        --@ContainerPKID, @BuyerID, @FeedlotID, @Date_Purchase, @Sex, @Origin_Country, @Origin_State,
        --@Origin_City, @Purchase_Name, @HDCT_In, @Cattle_Cost_Cwt, @Weight_Pay_Hd,
        --@Equity, @Interest_Rate, @Proj_Date_In, @Proj_Weight_Out_Avg, @Proj_Ship_Date, @Proj_CONV, @Proj_Ration_Cost,
        --@Proj_Yardage, @Proj_DL, @Proj_ADG, @Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd, @Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd, @Proj_MED, @Proj_Yardage_Hd,
        --@Proj_DL_Cost_Hd, @Proj_Freight_Hd, @Proj_Interest_Hd, @Proj_Realizers, @Proj_TotalCost_Hd, @Proj_Gain, @Proj_DOF,
        --@Proj_Breakeven, @Proj_COG, @Proj_Futures, @Proj_Basis, @Diff_On_Formula, @Hdg_Live_Cost, @Proj_PL_HD,
        --@Proj_PL_HD_Hdg, @Proj_PL_HD_Net, @Proj_ROI, @Purchase_Contract_No, @Age, @Condtion, @Quality,
        --@Breed, @Source_Loc, @Date_In, @Weight_Offtruck_Tot, @Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot, @Act_Pay_Weight_Tot, @Purchase_Type, @Notes, null


    --)


  set @SQL = 'insert into tblPurchases (
  ContainerPKID, 
  BuyerID, 
  FeedlotID, 
  Date_Purchase, 
  Sex, 
  Origin_Country, 
  Origin_State, 
  Origin_City, 
  Purchase_Name, 
  HDCT_In, 
  Cattle_Cost_Cwt, 
  Weight_Pay_Hd, 
  Equity, 
  Interest_Rate, 
  Proj_Date_In, 
  Proj_Weight_Out_Avg, 
  Proj_Ship_Date, 
  Proj_CONV, 
  Proj_Ration_Cost, 
  Proj_Yardage, 
  Proj_DL, 
  Proj_ADG, 
  Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd, 
  Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd, 
  Proj_MED, 
  Proj_Yardage_Hd, 
  Proj_DL_Cost_Hd, 
  Proj_Freight_Hd, 
  Proj_Interest_Hd, 
  Proj_Realizers, 
  Proj_TotalCost_Hd, 
  Proj_Gain, 
  Proj_DOF, 
  Proj_Breakeven, 
  Proj_COG, 
  Proj_Futures, 
  Proj_Basis, 
  Diff_On_Formula, 
  Hdg_Live_Cost, 
  Proj_PL_HD, 
  Proj_PL_HD_Hdg, 
  Proj_PL_HD_Net, 
  Proj_ROI, 
  Purchase_Contract_No, 
  Age, 
  Condtion, 
  Quality, 
  Breed, 
  Source_Loc, 
  Date_In, 
  Weight_Offtruck_Tot, 
  Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot, 
  Act_Pay_Weight_Tot, 
  Purchase_Type, 
  CustomerID, 
  Notes'
  set @SQL = @SQL + ') values (' + 
      @ContainerPKID + @Comma + 
      @BuyerID + @Comma + 
      @FeedlotID + @Comma + 
      @Date_Purchase + @Comma + 
      @Sex + @Comma + 
      @Origin_Country + @Comma + 
      @Origin_State + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Origin_City + @Comma + 
      @Purchase_Name + @Comma + 
      @HDCT_In + @Comma + 
      @Cattle_Cost_Cwt + @Comma +
      @Weight_Pay_Hd + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Equity + @Comma + 
      @Interest_Rate + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Date_In + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Weight_Out_Avg + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Ship_Date + @Comma + 
      @Proj_CONV + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Ration_Cost + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Proj_Yardage + @Comma + 
      @Proj_DL + @Comma + 
      @Proj_ADG + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd + @Comma + 
      @Proj_MED + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Yardage_Hd + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Proj_DL_Cost_Hd + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Freight_Hd + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Interest_Hd + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Realizers + @Comma + 
      @Proj_TotalCost_Hd + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Gain + @Comma + 
      @Proj_DOF + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Proj_Breakeven + @Comma + 
      @Proj_COG + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Futures + @Comma + 
      @Proj_Basis + @Comma + 
      @Diff_On_Formula + @Comma + 
      @Hdg_Live_Cost + @Comma + 
      @Proj_PL_HD + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Proj_PL_HD_Hdg + @Comma + 
      @Proj_PL_HD_Net + @Comma + 
      @Proj_ROI + @Comma + 
      @Purchase_Contract_No + @Comma + 
      @Age + @Comma + 
      @Condtion + @Comma + 
      @Quality + @Comma
  set @SQL = @SQL + 
      @Breed + @Comma + 
      @Source_Loc + @Comma + 
      @Date_In + @Comma + 
      @Weight_Offtruck_Tot + @Comma + 
      @Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot + @Comma + 
      @Act_Pay_Weight_Tot + @Comma + 
      @Purchase_Type + @Comma + 
      '1' + @Comma + 
      @Notes
  set @SQL = @SQL + ')'

  execute (@SQL)

  print @@Identity
```

**PROBLEM FOUND AND FIXED**

That was a pain, the problem was not with the SP but with the string sent to the SP from the application, one of the numbers was format with Group Digits which put a comma in the number. Using the execute command in the `SP` then created an even bigger mess :)

Thanks everyone for the input.

Comment: Yes you should specify the columns in your insert. The exact cause of your NULL error is because you have a string literal 'NULL' instead of NULL. And you can't convert that string to an int. Perhaps if you shared some details here we can help.

Comment: OK i added the column names and now its saying i have fewer names in the columns than i do in the values...... i double checked and counted them all (56 columns, 56 values).....this is becoming a nightmare, every time i make changes and start again its giving me different errors

Comment: Is there a reason you use four ` ' ` for the `@SA` variable? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you only need two. Unless you're actually wanting to add the single quote with the value. That could be why you're receiving some of the errors like the 'NULL' error.

Comment: I did not originally write this SP, this was just his style and its always worked, i think they are escaped because he uses them to build strings that are executed later..... i'm not entirely sure i don't follow his methods.....

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the list of columns into which you are inserting your values then SQL Server assumes that you are providing a value for each column.  If you specify the columns then SQL Server won't make any such assumptions.  To handle this you would:

```
Insert MyTable (column_name1, column_name2, etc) Values(<total of 55 values>)
```

That can be a lot of typing.  There are a couple of things to do in order to copy get the column names without having to type them all.  For example, you can

```
select name from syscolumns where object_name(id)='MyTable'
```

to get the list of columns and then edit away.

You can take it a little further by doing something like:

```
declare @s varchar(max) = ''
select @s = @s + case when @s = '' then '' else ', ' end + name 
  from syscolumns 
 where object_name(id)='MyTable'
print @s  -- Your list of columns to be used in the insert statement.
```

Comment: Or even easier, open up object explorer and drag the columns folder to a query window. It will drop all the columns neatly in a row ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using dynamic sql here? This is just adding a totally unnecessary level of complexity. Also, you should be using SCOPE_IDENTITY instead of @@IDENTITY. If the table you are inserting to has a trigger that inserts a row with an identity you will get that one instead of the identity value for tblPurchases.

```
insert into tblPurchases 
(
    ContainerPKID, 
    BuyerID, 
    FeedlotID, 
    Date_Purchase, 
    Sex, 
    Origin_Country, 
    Origin_State, 
    Origin_City, 
    Purchase_Name, 
    HDCT_In, 
    Cattle_Cost_Cwt, 
    Weight_Pay_Hd, 
    Equity, 
    Interest_Rate, 
    Proj_Date_In, 
    Proj_Weight_Out_Avg, 
    Proj_Ship_Date, 
    Proj_CONV, 
    Proj_Ration_Cost, 
    Proj_Yardage, 
    Proj_DL, 
    Proj_ADG, 
    Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd, 
    Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd, 
    Proj_MED, 
    Proj_Yardage_Hd, 
    Proj_DL_Cost_Hd, 
    Proj_Freight_Hd, 
    Proj_Interest_Hd, 
    Proj_Realizers, 
    Proj_TotalCost_Hd, 
    Proj_Gain, 
    Proj_DOF, 
    Proj_Breakeven, 
    Proj_COG, 
    Proj_Futures, 
    Proj_Basis, 
    Diff_On_Formula, 
    Hdg_Live_Cost, 
    Proj_PL_HD, 
    Proj_PL_HD_Hdg, 
    Proj_PL_HD_Net, 
    Proj_ROI, 
    Purchase_Contract_No, 
    Age, 
    Condtion, 
    Quality, 
    Breed, 
    Source_Loc, 
    Date_In, 
    Weight_Offtruck_Tot, 
    Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot, 
    Act_Pay_Weight_Tot, 
    Purchase_Type, 
    CustomerID, 
    Notes
) 
values 
(
    @ContainerPKID, 
    @BuyerID, 
    @FeedlotID, 
    @Date_Purchase, 
    @Sex, 
    @Origin_Country, 
    @Origin_State, 
    @Origin_City, 
    @Purchase_Name, 
    @HDCT_In, 
    @Cattle_Cost_Cwt, 
    @Weight_Pay_Hd, 
    @Equity, 
    @Interest_Rate, 
    @Proj_Date_In, 
    @Proj_Weight_Out_Avg, 
    @Proj_Ship_Date, 
    @Proj_CONV, 
    @Proj_Ration_Cost, 
    @Proj_Yardage, 
    @Proj_DL, 
    @Proj_ADG, 
    @Proj_Animal_Cost_Hd, 
    @Proj_Feed_Cost_Hd, 
    @Proj_MED, 
    @Proj_Yardage_Hd, 
    @Proj_DL_Cost_Hd, 
    @Proj_Freight_Hd, 
    @Proj_Interest_Hd, 
    @Proj_Realizers, 
    @Proj_TotalCost_Hd, 
    @Proj_Gain, 
    @Proj_DOF, 
    @Proj_Breakeven, 
    @Proj_COG, 
    @Proj_Futures, 
    @Proj_Basis, 
    @Diff_On_Formula, 
    @Hdg_Live_Cost, 
    @Proj_PL_HD, 
    @Proj_PL_HD_Hdg, 
    @Proj_PL_HD_Net, 
    @Proj_ROI, 
    @Purchase_Contract_No, 
    @Age, 
    @Condtion, 
    @Quality, 
    @Breed, 
    @Source_Loc, 
    @Date_In, 
    @Weight_Offtruck_Tot, 
    @Act_Cattle_Cost_Tot, 
    @Act_Pay_Weight_Tot, 
    @Purchase_Type, 
    '1', 
    @Notes
)

print SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: This is how i usually do it, i tried it and its also failing. i might try rewrite the whole thing again my way and see how it goes......i just don't understand why it keeps trying to force a value into the ID column and giving an error, this is a PK column using INDENTITY auto increment, but it seems to want to put one of the values into this field!!??

Comment: Are you saying that you always use dynamic sql for inserts? That is crazy!!! Of course we can't really help much because you never posted the actual table definition so the best anybody can do it guess.

Comment: i usually do it the way you posted above, i never use injection, like everyone says it gets messy handling all the apostrophe's etc....

Comment: sql injection is not something you use...it is something you do everything you can to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Cannot convert 'NULL' to datatype int', occur because this you tried insert Null in your primary key.

```
set @PurchaseValues = 'NULL|1|NULL|6/21/2016|S|USA|NULL|NULL|aaaa|0|5|55|0|0.0500|6/21/2016|444|2016-07-23 10:00|1|23|0|0.0300|12|2.75|4.47|0|0.00|0.22|0|0.02|0|7.46|389|32.42|1.68|0.01|44|0|0|44.000|187.90|0|187.90|15,174.47|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL'
```

When you split, the first argument is null and the primary key not be null

Comment: my primary key is not included in this string, the PK is auto incremental....this is why i don't understand what its trying to do....all the values in this string are just data. Their related columns are just basic columns which can be NULL

Comment: try use `(select CASE Data THEN 'NULL' NULL ESLE Data End from dbo.Split(@PurchaseValues, '|') where ID = 1)`
I think you use the string 'NULL' 
instead the argument NULL.
Replace all its arguments as the example

Answer (score 0):

Use the ISNULL function or the statement 'is null' to test for null. SQL uses 3-valued logic with Boolean statements:

```
----------------------------------------------
| field 1 | field 2 | f 1 = f 2 | f 1 <> f 2 |  
----------------------------------------------
|    1    |    0    |   false   |    true    |
|    1    |    1    |   true    |    false   |
|    1    |   null  |   null    |    null    |
|   null  |  null   |   null    |    null    |
```

The reason the logic works this way is because null, in a way, means 'unknown'. Therefore anytime you compare an unknown value, the equality is also unknown. 2 unknown values are not necessarily equal, nor are they necessarily unequal. The same logic applies to comparing a known value with an unknown value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the argument 43 '15,174.47'. It has a comma e probably broken this your structure when you concatenate your string.

Answer (score 0):

It look's like you imported the pipe (|)delimited file without specifying the deliminator, re-importing the file could give you the solution.

---

Here is the solution for what you have asked for: I used only five columns, modify as per your need

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(8000)= 'NULL|1|NULL|6/21/2016|S|USA'
SET @String  = @String +'|'

CREATE TABLE #temp(id INT IDENTITY(0,1),recordID AS (id /55),ColId AS (id % 55)+1 ,value VARCHAR(250))
WHILE(LEN(@String)>0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #temp(value)
SELECT left(@String,CHARINDEX('|',@String)-1)
set @String=SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('|',@String)+1,LEN(@String))

END 


SELECT 
    a1.value,
    a2.value,
    a3.value,
    a4.value,
    a5.value
FROM
  #temp a1
LEFT JOIN #temp a2 ON a1.recordID=a2.recordID AND a2.ColId=2
LEFT JOIN #temp a3 ON a1.recordID=a3.recordID AND a3.ColId=3
LEFT JOIN #temp a4 ON a1.recordID=a4.recordID AND a4.ColId=4
LEFT JOIN #temp a5 ON a1.recordID=a5.recordID AND a5.ColId=5
WHERE a1.ColId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I am still getting a little feedback on this thread so I just want to clear everything up to end this thread.

The reason the SQL was failing was because of the String it was receiving from outside. The string passed to he SP had an error which was not apparent and caused the SP to behave in a way that was confusing because i did not even realize you could manually set a Pre-Shared key field set to Auto-Increment using the Insert statement without specifying the columns to insert to.

The problem specifically was the string passed to the SP had a currency amount which contained a Comma, using the Execute Statement in the SP with this comma caused the server to think an extra column was involved and that is why the first value of 'NULL' was being pushed to the Pre-Shared Key column because we had an extra column.

I understand the markdowns in this thread however i think i did provide enough information to lure  the initial thoughts of a syntax or logical error away from the problem list. That said This problem baffled me for 6 hours until i finally noticed the string passed to the SP was causing the problem......

My advice to anyone else experiencing strange unexplainable behavior with queries or SP's is keep an open mind, methodically check the whole process from start to end and scrutinize everything. I also want to point out that if your confident in what your doing and just come across something similar, some unexplained behavior, read through the feedback but dont act on anthing that does just click in your mind, an example click would be something like 'omg thats it right there how did i miss that. Its greate that people help but be weary of things that can lead you away from the actual problem and confuse you even more......

**NOTE**

I will change the heading of this thread to something more meaningfull so anyone with a similar problem can at least see what happened to me....(assuming i can do that :))